X-Wing Starfighter
Today is May 4th, Star Wars day, so here's a Star Wars ASCII-art task. Output this image of an X-Wing starfighter:
\             /
o\           /o
V \(+)___(+)/ V
|  --/ | \--  |
  /(+)\|/(+)\
 /    |||    \
/o     |     o\
 V           V
 |           |

Your output may have any extra whitespace that doesn't affect the representation of the image. You may output a list of lines instead of a string with newlines.
This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins. May the 4th be with you!
(If it's May 5th in your timezone, try Sith TIE-Fighter)

Charcoal, 36 bytes
↑|VoＰ/²↖↑↑|Vo↘³Ｍ↑“↗↧ºXu⊘$…(s”↙↘|↑⁴‖Ｂ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
↑|VoＰ/²

Draw the bottom left leg.
↖↑↑|Vo↘³

Draw the top left leg.
Ｍ↑“↗↧ºXu⊘$…(s”

Draw the left body using a compressed string.
↙↘|↑⁴

Draw the middle of the body.
‖Ｂ

Reflect to complete the starfighter.

K (ngn/k), 96 bytes
Hardcode the left half, then reverse and replace \/() -> /\)( to get the other half.
`0:"/()\\"{y,1_|y^'x@3-x?y}/:8$";"\"\\;o\\;V \\(+)__;|  --/ |;  /(+)\\|; /    ||;/o     |; V; |"

Attempt This Online!

JavaScript (ES6), 125 bytes
_=>`09/
o08/o
V 0(+)___(+)/ V
|2--/ | 0--2|
2/(+)0|/(+)0
 /3|||30
/o4|4o0
 V8V
 |8|`.replace(/\d/g,n=>"".padEnd(n/.67)||"\\")

Try it online!

Vyxal Drj, 387 bitsv2, 48.375 bytes
` |/\-_)+(Vo`»¬W,Ze:iw≠ꜝ≬⊍eȦR`¡ßdĿ$»τ»÷Ṡ%]»fẇƛ8røM

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
011010111101100010101100010111010011011110100000111110000101110011010101110101111111100100001011101100001100010001000010010111111001000011011010111111001010110100011001100001011101110111110110100111000100101100111001011110110000011000101011001110101110010101101101001000110110111000010110110000110110110110011101100110000111100110010100110010010001111011011110011001001010000110111111101

-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

The hard-coded string can be »¬W,Ze:iw≠ꜝ≬⊍eȦR`¡ßdĿ$»` |/\-_)+(Vo`τ, although I'm not sure how to combine it with the r flag.. :/

r flag just switches the two

05AB1E, 48 bytes
•D¾ì6ªβh§ζƶwāZ·ªrΣ∍kÏª#8ñ2•" 
|/\-_)+(Vo"ÅвJ.B.º

Outputs as a list of lines.
Try it online. (The » in the footer joins the list by newlines. Feel free to remove it to see the actual result.)
Explanation:
Step 1: Draw the left side without trailing spaces:
by using this 05AB1E ASCII-art compression technique
•D¾ì6ªβh§ζƶwāZ·ªrΣ∍kÏª#8ñ2•
                # Push compressed integer 78542092356563376216422644276947767672388754200679396880402
" \n|/\-_)+(Vo" # Push this string
  Åв            # Convert the integer to custom base-" \n|/\-_)+(Vo",
                # basically convert it to base-length, and then index into the string
    J           # Join this list of characters to a single string

See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section How to compress large integers?) to understand why •D¾ì6ªβh§ζƶwāZ·ªrΣ∍kÏª#8ñ2• is 78542092356563376216422644276947767672388754200679396880402.
Try just this first step.
.B              # Split on newlines, but add trailing spaces to make all lines the same length
  .º            # Mirror the list of lines horizontally with overlap in the middle
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)

